# How to properly write a Django view for a Patch request

Tags: python, django, python-requests, http-patch

So I am making a view in Django, and I'm trying to use POST for creation, GET for fetching, I wanted to use PATCH for handling updations, but I am struggling to understand how to process an incoming PATCH request's data.

I am sending a PATCH request in POSTMAN, with form-data(key-value pairs), but when trying to access the data, `request.POST` or `request.PATCH` or `request.data` dont work. Only thing that works is `request.body` which is a byte string that I have to decode and I don't want to do something like that just to access the data, is there a better way to do this?

My question is, what is the right way to make a PATCH view and how to handle the data from an incoming request? Handling POST data seems so straightforward by doing request.POST, why is PATCH not as straightforward? What do i do? Should I not be using PATCH then? Is it better to use POST for updation as well?